# Unlisted Youtube videos in in-app purchase

Tags: android, ios, youtube, in-app-purchase

It's possible in youtube to add videos called unlisted videos, so no one can search for it or find it, but if someone knows the URL it's possible to browse it.

Is android & iOS allow proxy tools to listen to all http requests in the application?
Is is safe to put videos in youtube as unlisted videos?

the videos will be sold as in-pp purchase in iOS & Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for sure on Android you can use proxy tools like BurpSuite and Charles to sniff traffic incoming and outgoing.

To sniff HTTPS traffic, the user will have to install a custom security certificate on their device.

Comment: thank you @ataulm, BurpSuite and Charles cannot sniff iOS apps .. Is that right?

Comment: Don't know about iOS but i would assume there is also a way to do the same. I would suggest trying the YouTube Android API to fetch an unlisted video by its ID, watch the network traffic and see if the request includes the ID itself or a hash of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, in your YouTube account settings you can set videos as private. Here is a tutorial video on how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaSM_xcmkOI.  To protect your videos, you may want to make an embedded YouTube player rather than providing a link, because that could be copy/pasted and shared with others.

Comment: Hi @Alex J ... the problem is How could I add people to private videos? Is it possible with Youtube APIs? If Yes, My customers should have a Google account. Is that right?
And please tell me if you tried that before? Sharing your experience will really help. thank you in advance